# How to check if firewalld is blocking an incoming ip address?

Tags: fail2ban, firewalld

I have CentOS 7 with firewalld. I installed fail2ban and using the firewallcmd-new action. I am seeing bans in the fail2ban logs, and I want to check in firewallcmd if they are blocked. How can I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, I strongly recommend that you use `banaction = firewallcmd-ipset` as this will provide much better performance when the ban list starts getting large.

Now, with any of fail2ban's firewalld actions, it will add a direct rule, which you can inspect with `firewall-cmd --direct --get-all-rules`:

```
# firewall-cmd --direct --get-all-rules
ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports ssh -m set --match-set fail2ban-sshd src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 0:65535 -m set --match-set fail2ban-nginx-http-auth src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -m set --match-set fail2ban-nginx-wordpress-login src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

As you can see, I am using `firewallcmd-ipset`, so the actual banned IP addresses are not listed here. Instead, I find them with `ipset list`:

```
# ipset list
Name: fail2ban-sshd
Type: hash:ip
Revision: 1
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536 timeout 600
Size in memory: 16528
References: 1
Members:

Name: fail2ban-nginx-http-auth
Type: hash:ip
Revision: 1
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536 timeout 600
Size in memory: 16528
References: 1
Members:

Name: fail2ban-nginx-wordpress-login
Type: hash:ip
Revision: 1
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536 timeout 86400
Size in memory: 40656
References: 1
Members:
108.62.172.244 timeout 70819
108.62.172.121 timeout 82750
212.252.164.233 timeout 69907
108.62.24.87 timeout 58024
23.19.127.20 timeout 84310
### many more omitted...
```

Comment: And before you ask, my `fail2ban-sshd` jail _is_ working fine. But sshd itself is [secured](https://stribika.github.io/2015/01/04/secure-secure-shell.html) in such a way that almost no bots can actually talk to it.

Answer (score 3):

Details here: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD#Which_zones_are_available.3F

- List all zones with the enabled features.

  `firewall-cmd --list-all-zones`
- Print zone  with the enabled features. If zone is omitted, the default zone will be used.

  `firewall-cmd [--zone=<zone>] --list-all`

If the above command is not displaying enough info, you can try

- iptables Direct Interface (Quoted from:[Introduction to FirewallD on CentOS](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/firewalls/introduction-to-firewalld-on-centos))

For the most advanced usage, or for iptables experts, FirewallD provides a direct interface that allows you to pass raw iptables commands to it. Direct Interface rules are not persistent unless the --permanent is used.

To see all custom chains or rules added to FirewallD:

`firewall-cmd --direct --get-all-chains`

`firewall-cmd --direct --get-all-rules`